# Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:18

Tags: typescript, npm, angular15

el siguiente error se presenta al intentar instalar @angular/fire

```
Interface 'DocumentSnapshotExists<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
  The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData | undefined'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
    13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
                                               ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.
  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
    13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
                                               ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined` constraint.


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:23:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
  The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

23 export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:23:40
    23 export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {
                                              ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:26:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'QuerySnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>'.
  Types of property 'docs' are incompatible.
    Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>[]'.
      Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>' is not assignable to type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
        The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

26 export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:26:32
    26 export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot {
                                      ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:29:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DocumentChange<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentChange<DocumentData>'.
  The types returned by 'doc.data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

29 export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:29:33
    29 export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange {
                                       ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.
```

### Error Angular 15 y firebas

Encontre este [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73289406/4668184) pero no me funcionó aun desinstalando, firebase y volviendolo a instalar.